# Magento product category missing in breadcrumb

Tags: magento, breadcrumbs

On the home page of my Magento site, I used the following code to add a Latest Products block

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="2" template="catalog/product/random.phtml"}}
```

When clicking on the latest products, some would work (the ones that worked showed a full breadcrumb) and others would lead to an error:
Fatal error: Call to a member function getName() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/riderseyewear.net/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/fortium/default/template/page/1column-product.phtml on line 80

The error is described more here https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4VYZ.png

In that 1column-product.phtml file, I went to line 80 and changed

```
$currentcat = Mage::registry('current_category')->getName();
```

to

```
$currentcat = Mage::registry('current_product')->getName();
```

Changing this line removed the error. However, now the category name will not show up in the breadcrumbs when clicking on a product. The breadcrumb shows HOME/PRODUCT_NAME instead of HOME/CATEGORY_NAME/PRODUCT_NAME

How can I get the full breadcrumb to show up while also not receiving the Fatal error?

Answer (score 4):

Follow this link http://dltr.org/blog/magento/381/Magento-Force-Display-Full-Breadcrumb-Path.
Perfectly works for me. let me know if i could help you more.

Comment: Thank you but I added the bit of code to the breadcrumbs.php file and it still has the same results. When clicking on a latest product from the home page, the breadcrumb still shows "home/product_name" instead of "home/category_name/product_name"

Comment: need to change only _prepareLayout function in breadcrumb page.copy all the code inside _prepareLayout() function from the above reference url.Also make sure breadcrumb working fine from category page product list/grid.

Comment: Here is the link to the site http://riderseyewear.net/index.php Try clicking on one of the Latest Products to see the error I'm receiving regarding line 80 in 1column-product.phtml this is the current line 80    
    $currentcat = Mage::registry('current_category')->getName();

Comment: Your breadcrumb working fine.Problem was on 1column-product.phtml page which u are using on product details page.Try once to change the template.I think your are using subcategory or may be product category is missing.try to get parent category name of current category.

Comment: wanna see your 1column-product.phtml page.

Comment: Is there any solution? The DLTR's solution isn't working fine for me.

Comment: Works perfectly for me: http://dltr.org/blog/magento/381/Magento-Force-Display-Full-Breadcrumb-Path

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite old, but I'd like to share my solution anyway as it doesn't override/clone any core files.

1. In your custom module add the following to your `config.xml`:

   ```
   <config>
       ...
       <frontend>
           <events>
               <catalog_controller_product_init>
                   <observers>
                       <breadcrumb_categorypath_product_init>
                           <type>singleton</type>
                           <class><Your Namespace>_<Your Module>_Model_Observer</class>
                           <method>fullBreadcrumbCategoryPath</method>
                       </breadcrumb_categorypath_product_init>
                   </observers>
               </catalog_controller_product_init>
           </events>
       </frontend>
   </config>
   ```
2. Create an `Observer.php` in `/app/code/local/<Your Namespace>/<Your Module>/Model/`
3. Add the following to your `Observer.php`:

   ```
   class <Your Namespace>_<Your Module>_Model_Observer {
       public function fullBreadcrumbCategoryPath(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
           $currentProduct = Mage::registry( 'current_product' );
           $storeRootCatId     = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();

           if( $currentProduct ) {
               $categories = $currentProduct->getCategoryCollection()->addAttributeToSelect( 'name' );
               foreach( $categories as $_category ) {
                   $catIdPath = '1/' . $storeRootCatId . '/';
                   if( 0 === strpos($_category->getData('path'), $catIdPath) ) {
                       Mage::unregister( 'current_category' );
                       Mage::register( 'current_category', $_category );
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. You should be good to go.

Comment: Setting larger setPageSize(1) argument lets you display full category path, not only the first part